# Transfer file to Ubuntu(15.04) to Windows(8.1) with a cross-over cable between two computers

Tags: windows, 15.04, file-sharing, 8.10

I need transfer around 125 gb from my laptop(Ubuntu 15.04) to another one(Windows 8.1), but I don't have a removable hard disk. I have a UTP cable , but I dont know how transfer this files across the UTP cable, and how create the local net network?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**FROM:** http://www.trickyways.com/2014/06/share-files-between-windows-8-and-ubuntu/

1. install samba `sudo apt-get install system-config-samba`
2. open it (it should be in menu aka dash)
3. Once it opens up, go to “Preferences” menu and then select “Server Settings”. Here type the Workgroup name your Windows is a member of, for example type workgroup in the “Workgroup text box” because the default “workgroup name” used in Windows is “workgroup”. Click OK button to save the settings.

[image]

4. If you got an error called Could not display “network:///”. Nautilus cannot handle “network” locations.
   Then you have to execute this command in the Ubuntu Terminal.

`sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends`

5. Enable file and printer sharing on Windows

*Before joining workgroup on computer, make sure the workgroup name on Windows computer is same that you given in Samba server settings on Ubuntu. See [this guide](http://www.trickyways.com/2014/01/find-change-workgroup-name-windows-8.x/) if you want to change Workgroup name.
You also have to ensure that file sharing is enabled in Windows 8. If not, you won’t be able to access file from other systems so let’s get started. To enable file sharing in Windows, on Windows Desktop press “Windows+W” keys from the keyboard which will open up the Charms Settings Search bar.
When this opens up, search for “manage sharing” and then click on the resulted search.*

[image]

*After this, turn on the file and printing sharing in the private/public network profiles. You also have the option to turn on file sharing for all network profiles. Save when you are finished.*

[image]

*Since now both of the systems belong to the same Workgroup, reboot both computers. When you login, you will be able to see the other system from both of your machines.*

[image]

### EDIT:

I*f you find  error then you have to execute the following commands .*

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install glade
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

Comment: I cant open Samba!

Comment: Does it say something, or it just won't open?

Comment: Only the program dont open, i install samba, i search in the dask, samba asking me my password but dont open!